# how to access jsonp in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, jsonp

I am trying to access the body of a json page that has a callback url.
In client side it is easy by using jquery and using jsonp option and so on...

How do i do it on the nodejs server side to get the title for example??

the url prints out: `data({"log":{"title":"example","description" ...`

```
var http = require("http");

function getPost(){
    var reqest = http.get("http://news.example.com/api/read/json?callback=data", function(response){
        response.setEncoding('utf8');
        response.on('data', function(posts){
            var x = JSON.parse(posts);
            var callback = function(x){
                console.log(callback);
            }
        });
    });
} 

getPost();
```

Comment: If you remove `?callback=data` are you sure the API doesn't return just JSON, as there is no need for JSONP on the serverside

Comment: nop i get a var test = json data....   I need just the json object and nothing else.